# What is the meaning of this confusing sentence?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

> We came to a spot than which mine eyes have seldom seen a lovelier site.

Is this sentence even grammatically correct? 
We were asked to find the error in sentence and when I asked my teacher about it he just said "its an excerpt from an old literature but don't know from which one and we should always opt for no error in these literature related questions".

Comment: Please cite (name) the source that you are quoting and link to it.

Comment: Please always include a source for this sort of question. Knowing who said/wrote it is very helpful as is context for it.

Comment: @AlanCarmack don't know about the book. It was asked in my exam.

Comment: What was the question in the exam? Are you sure you copied it correctly? And, hello we meet again! :) Despite my previous attempts to squeeze the title and the name of an author in your last post, you steadfastly refused, for some inexplicable reason. -1 for lack of any research, and for not citing that it came from an (English?) exam paper.

Comment: It looks like this comes from ["High School English Grammar and Composition Book"](https://books.google.com/books?id=m2ctDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA182&lpg=PA182&dq=We+came+to+a+spot+than+which+mine+eyes+have+seldom+seen+a+lovelier+site&source=bl&ots=VNeakHmFo4&sig=H8B0c3MfQ21bJzidfWtwcEl3KYs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi86tT7mI_QAhVh0oMKHYRIBvMQ6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=We%20came%20to%20a%20spot%20than%20which%20mine%20eyes%20have%20seldom%20seen%20a%20lovelier%20site&f=false).

Comment: Anyway, I don't know if the authors wrote this sentence themselves or got it from somewhere else, but it's extremely old-fashioned and stilted-sounding to modern ears, and a strange choice for teaching English language learners today.

Comment: @stangdon and copied incorrectly the last word should be **sight**.

Comment: @Mari-LouA lol I am sure I copied it correctly. We were asked to find the error in sentence and when I asked my teacher about it he just said "its an excerpt from an old literature but don't know from which one and we should always opt for no error in these literature related  questions".

Comment: Downvote retracted. :)

Comment: The texts on which Wren & Martin based parts of their 1972 "grammar book" predate Kipling, but the Hindi edition, especially the one "improved" by a Mr Rao, is still being used to butcher English for students across India, for some reason. Take your book to the incinerator.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is old-fashioned—*mine* is no longer used as a determiner—but it is grammatically acceptable and ordinary. The relative clause launched by *than which* has this as its underlying 'canonical' clause:

```
                  mine eyes have seldom seen a lovelier site than [this spot].
```

[This spot] is represented by relative *which*; that takes its place at the front of the clause and 'pied-pipes' (carries along with it) the preposition *than* whose object it is, leaving a 'gap' (_) in the clause:

```
                 mine eyes have seldom seen a lovelier site than _____.
                                                                   ↓
          ------------------------------------------------←[than which] 
      ____↓_____  
      than which mine eyes have seldom seen a lovelier site
```

Answer (score -3):

That is definitely archaic English ("mine eyes" is the telling phrase), so you need to make allowances for changes in English over the ages.

I break down the sentence as follows:

1. > We came to a spot than

   We arrived at a location ***then***,
2. > which mine eyes have seldom seen

   where my eyes have hardly ever seen
3. > a lovelier site.

   a more beautiful sight/site.

That last word tickles me! Because it's the speaker's eyes, you'd expect "sight" - but since the subject of discussion is a location, "site" is also valid.

Comment: In this case `site` probably means 'location'

Comment: Agreed completely! But given the poetical phrasing of the rest it, the homonym tickles me.